# Cordova Dialog Plugin: insert HTML tags in notification.alert message

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am developing a Cordova hybrid application. I need to click on the button and display a customized error message to the user. However, I realize that Cordova Dialog Plugin, `notification.alert()` body message does not support HTML tags. May I know how can I add HTML tags into message body of `notification.alert()` so that I have a customized notification dialog box in my Cordova application? The following is my code.

```
function alertDismissed() {
    console.log("alert has been triggered and dismissed ");
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    '<html><h1>Error!!></h1><br><a>Source Code Error</a></html>',
    alertDismissed,
    'Asset Details',
    'Ok'
);
```

Comment: Create a dialog box on your own using HTML and Css instead of using Cordova dialog plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use your own html and css to show popup instead of using cordova dialog plugin

Useful Plugin to show dialog box http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/

If you are using ionic framework this will be helpful https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert

Comment: Solved my problem.